# F# Suppress Warnings

Tags: f#

Sometimes I get annoying pattern matching and indent warnings when compiling F#. Is there a way to disable warnings? I'm pretty OCD over warnings.

Comment: Maybe resolve the warnings? :)

Comment: I'd be really careful about shutting off pattern matching warnings.  And considering that F# syntax can use indentation to determine scope, I wouldn't just ignore those warnings--I'd try to understand them.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a per-instance basis? A few times I have cases that know things the compiler doesn't, for example, the number of groups a regex match will produce.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case you forget, you can type

```
let rec x = lazy(x.Value)
```

and get the warning

> This and other recursive references to
>   the object(s) being defined will be
>   checked for initialization-soundness
>   at runtime through the use of a
>   delayed reference. This is because you
>   are defining one or more recursive
>   objects, rather than recursive
>   functions. This warning may be
>   suppressed by using '#nowarn "40"' or
>   '--nowarn:40'.

which shows that you can use either the compiler flag `--nowarn` on the command-line, or use the hash-directive `#nowarn` in your code.  The warning number for each warning will be part of the build output (the Visual Studio error list does not display the numbers, so if in VS, build and then inspect the build output).  Also, if inside VS, you can go to the project properties page, "Build" tab, and use the "warning level" selector and "suppress warnings" field (a semicolon-delimited list of numbers) to control which warnings are diplayed via the VS UI.

(BTW, I believe `#nowarn` only turns off the warning in the current file, whereas `--nowarn` turns it off for the entire project being compiled.)

Answer (score 4):

See: [Compiler Options (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx)

> `--nowarn:<int-list>`:
>
> Disable specific warnings listed by
>   number. Separate each warning number
>   by a comma. You can discover the
>   warning number for any warning from
>   the compilation output.
>
> This compiler option is equivalent to
>   the C# compiler option of the same
>   name. For more information, see
>   [/nowarn (C# Compiler Options).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f28x9z3.aspx)